# How to I export an excel print file using vbs, with page numbers in the footer?

Tags: excel, pdf, vbscript

I have a macro that prints a spreadsheet to pdf file.

**The left and right footer values for page number and number of pages, is not getting exported**

instead of:

```
1                                   12
```

I get this:

```
&R                                  &L
```

The parameters being passed are **&P** and **&N**, so **&R** and **&L** are a complete mystery.

This is my code, ( my apologies for the lack of declarations.. this is just testing an idea...).
Most of the code is simply a macro recording. All the page setup and page number info is recorded. My contributions are the declarations, loop structure and the file export code at the bottom.

It all works except for the lack of page numbers.

```
Sub TEST()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
COP = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields("SEC USER DEPARTMENT").PivotItems().Count
For PT = 1 To COP
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields("SEC USER DEPARTMENT")
        .CurrentPage = .PivotItems(PT).Value
    End With
    SEC_USER_DEPARTMENT = Trim(Cells(1, 2).Value)
    DT = "121519"
    HOME = "C:\Gunhead\_ANALYTICS\MSP Reports\"
    FNAME1 = "Passport SECU "
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields("WORKSTATION ID"). _
    ShowDetail = True
    LASTROW = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    LASTCOL = Cells(6, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(LASTROW, LASTCOL)).Select
    With Selection
        .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
        .WrapText = True
    End With
    Selection.Rows.AutoFit
    Selection.Columns.AutoFit
    Application.PrintCommunication = False
    With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
        .PrintTitleRows = "$1:$6"
        .PrintTitleColumns = ""
    End With
    Application.PrintCommunication = True
    ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = ""
    Application.PrintCommunication = False
    With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
        .LeftHeader = ""
        .CenterHeader = ""
        .RightHeader = ""
        **.LeftFooter = "&P"**
        .CenterFooter = ""
        **.RightFooter = "&N"**
        .LeftMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.7)
        .RightMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.7)
        .TopMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.75)
        .BottomMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.75)
        .HeaderMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.3)
        .FooterMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.3)
        .PrintHeadings = False
        .PrintGridlines = False
        .PrintComments = xlPrintNoComments
        .PrintQuality = 600
        .CenterHorizontally = False
        .CenterVertically = False
        .Orientation = xlPortrait
        .Draft = False
        .PaperSize = xlPaperLetter
        .FirstPageNumber = xlAutomatic
        .Order = xlDownThenOver
        .BlackAndWhite = False
        .Zoom = False
        .FitToPagesWide = 1
        .FitToPagesTall = False
        .PrintErrors = xlPrintErrorsDisplayed
        .OddAndEvenPagesHeaderFooter = False
        .DifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter = False
        .ScaleWithDocHeaderFooter = True
        .AlignMarginsHeaderFooter = True
    End With
    Application.PrintCommunication = True
    Sheets("PIVOT").Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(LASTROW, LASTCOL)).Select
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat _
    Type:=xlTypePDF, _
    Filename:=HOME & FNAME1 & "-" & SEC_USER_DEPARTMENT & " - " & DT & ".PDF", _
    Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
    OpenAfterPublish:=True
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is:

```
.LeftFooter = "Page &P Of &NN "
```